# Java 8 GroupBy one field and then mapping to multiple fields

Tags: java, java-8

I have an object structure like

```
class Person{
   String userId;
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   Set<Courses> courses = new HashSet<Courses>();
}
```

Database records are like this (actually user firstName and lastName is from another table, but for simplicity I am putting as below):

```
user1 John  Smith course1 
user1 John  Smith course2
user1 John  Smith course3
user2 Jack  Smith course1
user2 Jack  Smith course2
```

From database retrieved the results into `List<Map<String, Object>> resultSet`.

Now I need to group by userId and then map courses into Set and create a `List<Person>` objects.

Right now I am able to group by userId and collect the courses into set but not able to map firstName and lastName.

```
Map<Object, Set<Object>> userList = resultSet.stream().collect()
.Collectors.groupingBy( usr -> usr.get("user_id"),
     Collectors.mapping( usr -> usr.get("courses"), Collectors.toSet()) ));

// Result {user1=[course1, course2, course3]}
```

And then I am creating Person Object

```
List<Person> = userList.entrySet.stream().
              .map( usr -> new Person(usr.getKey().toString(),
                               (Set<Courses)(Set<?>)usr.getValue()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

How can I get the firstName , lastName in the groupingby step and use it to create object ??

Comment: What is the type of `resultSet`?

Comment: Type of resultset is List<Map<String,Object>> is the query result from db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try defining your custom collector passed as a downstream function to a `Collectors.groupingBy()`. Consider following example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PersonGroupByExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<Map<String, Object>> input = Arrays.asList(
                new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                    put("userId", "user1");
                    put("firstName", "John");
                    put("lastName", "Smith");
                    put("courses", "course1");
                }},
                new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                    put("userId", "user1");
                    put("firstName", "John");
                    put("lastName", "Smith");
                    put("courses", "course2");
                }},
                new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                    put("userId", "user1");
                    put("firstName", "John");
                    put("lastName", "Smith");
                    put("courses", "course3");
                }},
                new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                    put("userId", "user2");
                    put("firstName", "Jack");
                    put("lastName", "Smith");
                    put("courses", "course1");
                }},
                new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                    put("userId", "user2");
                    put("firstName", "Jack");
                    put("lastName", "Smith");
                    put("courses", "course2");
                }}
        );

        final Collection<Person> result = input.stream()
                .parallel()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it.get("userId"), Collector.of(
                        // Start with an empty Person object
                        Person::new,
                        // Collect a list of map objects grouped by the same userId into a single Person object
                        (person, map) -> {
                            // Override common properties
                            person.setUserId(map.getOrDefault("userId", "").toString());
                            person.setFirstName(map.getOrDefault("firstName", "").toString());
                            person.setLastName(map.getOrDefault("lastName", "").toString());
                            // Add person's course to a courses set
                            person.getCourses().add(new Course(map.getOrDefault("courses", "").toString()));
                        },
                        // Combiner function that join partials results (for parallel execution)
                        (person, person2) -> {
                            person.getCourses().addAll(person2.getCourses());
                            return person;
                        }
                ))).values();

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    static class Person {
        String userId;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

        public Person() {}

        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public Set<Course> getCourses() {
            return courses;
        }

        public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
            this.courses = courses;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "userId='" + userId + '\'' +
                    ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                    ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                    ", courses=" + courses +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static class Course {
        String id;

        public Course(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Course{" +
                    "id='" + id + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

`Collectors.groupingBy()` groups all entries by `userId` field and then a downstream function with custom collector reduces a list of `Map<String, Object>` entries grouped by the same `userId` to a single `Person` instance containing all courses. I've used `Person` and `Course` POJO's just to illustrate the flow, also input `List<Map<String, Object>>` is used as an illustration of the transformation process.

In the end we call `Map.values()` method to return a `Collection<Person>` instead of `Map<String, Person>`.

Running this example creates following output:

```
Person{userId='user1', firstName='John', lastName='Smith', courses=[Course{id='course1'}, Course{id='course3'}, Course{id='course2'}]}
Person{userId='user2', firstName='Jack', lastName='Smith', courses=[Course{id='course2'}, Course{id='course1'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I am not having input users List as List<Person>. I have having input as a List<Map<String, Object>> , which makes it had to get the course and set in object, can you please help on this...

Comment: @RinsenS I've updated the example to use `List<Map<String, Object>>` as an input.

Comment: Awesome, I also just now completed. Thanks for the solution too

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` instead of `Collectors.groupingBy`. You will achieve the grouping via the merge function passed to `toMap`.

It will create some unnecessary `Person` instances, but the final result will contain what you want.

```
Map<String,Person> persons = 
    resultSet.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(usr -> usr.get("user_id"),
                                       usr -> new Person(usr.get("user_id"),usr.get("first_name"),usr.get("last_name"),usr.get("course")),
                                       (p1,p2)->{p1.addCourses(p2.getCourses()); return p1;}));
```

This is assuming you have the relevant constructor and methods in `Person` class.

Comment: Oh but is it possible to use groupingby as I am trying to learn it

Comment: @RinsenS I'm not sure.

Comment: Its performance better a bit `(p1, p2) -> {
                                    if (p1.getCourses().size() > p2.getCourses().size()) {
                                        p1.getCourses().addAll(p2.getCourses());
                                        return p1;
                                    }else {
                                        p2.getCourses().addAll(p1.getCourses());
                                        return p2;
                                    }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use reducing.

The idea is map each row with a Person object with single `courses` set, then group by and reducing.

```
Map<String, Person> people = userList = resultSet.stream()
    .map(v -> toPerson())
    .collect(groupingBy(Person::getId, reducing(null, (p1, p2) -> {
          p1.getCourses().addAll(p2.getCourses); 
          return p1;
    })));
```

Hope you get the point.